# List available times from 2 DateTimes

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I know this one may come across a little confusing, I'm just trying to contemplating the best way of putting it across! I've posted this on a couple of forums now but I don't seem to be having any luck. Hopefully someone can offer some suggestions on how to do this.

**Example table (tbl_Bookings)**

```
ID  DateStarted       DateEnded         RoomID
1   16/07/2012 09:00  16/07/2012 10:00    1
2   16/07/2012 12:00  16/07/2012 13:00    1
```

Basically, I want to enter 2 date times, such as 16/07/2012 08:30 and 16/07/2012 13:30, and it will query my example table above and return 'available' times, IE, I'd like it to output the following.

```
16/07/2012 08:30 - 16/07/2012 09:00
16/07/2012 10:00 - 16/07/2012 12:00
16/07/2012 13:00 - 16/07/2012 13:30
```

My question is, is this entirely possible in SQL? I've tried to think of how to do it in VB and I'm struggling with that one too. My idea/attempt has been using Ron Savage's fn_daterange (as shown below)

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where name = 'fn_daterange') drop function fn_daterange;
go
create function fn_daterange
(
@MinDate as datetime,
@MaxDate as datetime,
@intval  as datetime
)
returns table
as
return
WITH times (startdate, enddate, intervl) AS
(
SELECT @MinDate as startdate, @MinDate + @intval - .0000001 as enddate, @intval as intervl
UNION ALL
SELECT startdate + intervl as startdate, enddate + intervl as enddate, intervl as intervl
FROM times
WHERE startdate + intervl <= @MaxDate
)
select startdate, enddate from times;
go
```

I was then going to call it by using the below but my problem is, me.DateEnded is outside of dr.enddate and therefore the occurance would be '0':

```
SELECT dr.startdate, dr.enddate, count(me.DateStarted) as occurrence
FROM fn_daterange('16/07/2012 08:30', '16/07/2012 13:30', '00:30:00' ) dr
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Bookings me
ON me.DateStarted BETWEEN dr.startdate AND dr.enddate
AND me.DateEnded BETWEEN dr.startdate AND dr.enddate)
GROUP BY dr.startdate, dr.enddate
```

Can anyone possibly suggest a better way of doing this or hopefully offer a solution to the way I'm trying to do it currently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What time is `16/07/2012 09:90`?

Comment: What dbms are you using, SQL-Server (which version)? Basically you have a start datetime and a end datetime (hence a TimeSpan. Now you want to find the half-hours which are free(not booked). Is this correct?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, oops, have amended 09:90, thanks Tim :)

Comment: General points - Don't use `BETWEEN`, always explicitly define ranges as 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive' (especially for dates).  Don't suffix (or prefix) columns with their datatypes - use something like `startedAt`, `endedBy`, etc.  End-of-range information is often derived, especially when dealing with timespans, and shouldn't be stored, if possible (given performance considerations) - try to store deriving information instead.  End-dates, when necessary, should be as you've done here (start of next available), so that exclusive upper works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have a working solution in SQL.  This assumes that the data in `tbl_Bookings` is consistent, ie no start/end times overlap for a given room.  Probably a simpler way, but the trick was to order the bookings and pair up end times with the following start times.  There are two extra queries unioned on to get any intervals after your specified `Start` but before the first booking.  Likewise for `End`.

**EDIT:** Added `WHERE NOT EXISTS` guards to the last two queries in case `@Start` or `@End` fell within a booked interval.

```sql
DECLARE @Start DateTime = '05/07/2012 08:30'
DECLARE @End DateTime = '05/07/2012 13:30'

;WITH Bookings (RoomId, RowNum, Started, Ended) AS (
     SELECT RoomId,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RoomId ORDER BY DateStarted) AS RowNum,
     DateStarted, DateEnded
     FROM tbl_Bookings
)
SELECT RoomId, B.Ended AS S, C.Started AS E
FROM Bookings B
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT B2.Started FROM Bookings B2
    WHERE B2.RowNum = B.RowNum + 1
    AND B2.Started <= @End
    AND B2.RoomId = B.RoomId
) C
WHERE B.Ended >= @Start

UNION

-- Show any available time from @Start until the next DateStarted, unless @Start 
-- falls within a booked interval.
SELECT RoomId, @Start, MIN(DateStarted)
FROM tbl_Bookings
WHERE DateStarted > @Start
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Bookings WHERE Started < @Start AND Ended > @Start
    )
GROUP BY RoomId

UNION

-- Show any available time from the last DateEnded to @End, unless @End 
-- falls within a booked interval.
SELECT RoomId, MAX(DateEnded), @End
FROM tbl_Bookings
WHERE DateEnded < @End
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Bookings WHERE Started < @End AND Ended > @End
    )
GROUP BY RoomId
```

Working [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24476/4)

Comment: Just for "completeness" I have duplicated this at [data.se] [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75613/so11511634).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to solve the problem using sets but the following cursor based approach should work. This is how you'd do it in VB or C#:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAvailableTimes
(
    @MinDate datetime,
    @MaxDate datetime
)
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
    DateStarted datetime,
    DateEnded datetime,
    RoomID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateStarted datetime
    DECLARE @DateEnded datetime
    DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime
    DECLARE @RoomID int
    DECLARE @CurrentRoom int

    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DateStarted, DateEnded, RoomID 
        FROM tbl_Bookings 
        WHERE DateStarted BETWEEN @MinDate AND @MaxDate
            OR DateEnded BETWEEN @MinDate AND @MaxDate
        ORDER BY RoomID, DateStarted

    SET @CurrentRoom = 0

    OPEN c
    FETCH NEXT FROM c
    INTO @DateStarted, @DateEnded, @RoomID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF @CurrentRoom <> @RoomID BEGIN
            IF @CurrentRoom <> 0 AND @CurrentDate < @MaxDate BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @result VALUES (@CurrentDate, @MaxDate, @CurrentRoom)
            END

            SET @CurrentDate = @MinDate
            SET @CurrentRoom = @RoomID
        END

        IF @CurrentDate < @DateStarted BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @result VALUES (@CurrentDate, @DateStarted, @CurrentRoom)
        END

        SET @CurrentDate = @DateEnded

        FETCH NEXT FROM c
        INTO @DateStarted, @DateEnded, @RoomID
    END
    CLOSE c
    DEALLOCATE c

    IF @CurrentRoom <> 0 AND @CurrentDate < @MaxDate BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @result VALUES (@CurrentDate, @MaxDate, @CurrentRoom)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

The following call will now get you the result you're looking for on your test data.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetAvailableTimes('20120716 8:30', '20120716 13:30')
```

I've also assumed that there could be more than one room and you're looking for available times in all of them.

I only quickly tested the function therefore I'm pretty sure there are still some border cases that are not properly addressed. But you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with the following logic.  Create a record for the period between the desired start time and the first start time you see in the data, if any.  Create a record for the period between the desired end time and the last end time you see in the data, if any.  Then, create the in-between records for the times you have.

The following query has this idea.  I'm not sure if it works when the desired start and end time is in the middle of a period that is booked.

```
with const as (select @starttime as StartTime, @endtime as EndTime)
select *
from ((Select c.StartTime, MIN(DateStarted), RoomId
       from tbl_Bookings b cross join const c
       where b.DateStarted >= c.StartTime
       group by RoomID
       having c.StartTime <> MIN(DateStarted)
      ) union all
      (Select max(DateEnded), c.EndTime, RoomId
       from tbl_Bookings b cross join const c
       where b.DateEnded <= c.EndTime
       group by RoomID
       having c.EndTime <> max(DateEnded)
      ) union all
      (select *
       from (select b.DateEnded as DateStarted, min(b.DateStarted) as DateEnded
             from tbl_Bookings b join
                  tbl_Bookings bnext
                  on b.RoomId = bnext.RoomId and
                     bnext.DateStarted > b.DateStarted cross join
                  const c
             where b.DateStarted < c.endtime and
                   b.DateEnded > c.StartTime and
                   bnext.DateStart < c.EndTime and
                   bnext.DateEnded > c.StartTime
             group by b.DateEnded
            ) b cross join const c
       where DateStarted <> DateEnded
      )
     )
```

The last subquery is rather complicated.  It is doing a self join to get the equivalent of the lead() function.